# Integrate IBM message hub with IBM BPM

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-bpm, message-hub

I am following message hub java sample from github. I created my own version of Kafka producer and it runs fine on a J2Se env using java main application. Code snippet below -

```html
String jasslocation = "C:\\HOME\\Technical\\bluemix\\git\\message-hub-samples\\java\\message-hub-kafka-ssl\\resources" + File.separator + "jaas.conf";
  System.setProperty(JAAS_CONFIG_PROPERTY, jasslocation);
  
  Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        props.put("bootstrap.servers","kafka02-prod02.messagehub.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:9093");
        props.put("acks","all");
     //   props.put("block.on.bu","true");
        props.put("batch.size","1");
        props.put("security.protocol","SASL_SSL");
        props.put("ssl.protocol","TLSv1.2");
        props.put("ssl.enabled.protocols","TLSv1.2");
        props.put("ssl.truststore.location","C:\\IBM\\BPM857\\java_1.7_64\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
        //props.put("ssl.truststore.location","C:\\IBM\\IID\\v8.5\\jdk\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
        
        props.put("ssl.truststore.password","changeit");
        props.put("ssl.truststore.type","JKS");
        props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm","HTTPS");
        
        String topic="mytopic";
        String message="publish message to a topic";
        try {
         
          KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer;
          kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]>(props);
          ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic,message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         
          RecordMetadata recordMetadata = kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord).get();
          //getting RecordMetadata is possible to validate topic, partition and offset
          System.out.println("topic where message is published : " + recordMetadata.topic());
          System.out.println("partition where message is published : " + recordMetadata.partition());
          System.out.println("message offset # : " + recordMetadata.offset());
          kafkaProducer.close();
```

kafka client version - 0.90

When i wrap this code in a J2EE MDB and deploy it on BPM server. When MDB fires, the thread keeps waiting on send() :-

RecordMetadata recordMetadata = kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord).get();

and times out after sometime. It does not throw any other exception or error.

My question is that in order to use kafka client api from inside BPM, do I have to perform any additional steps like ssl configuration etc.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you may need to use kafka 0.10

Comment: I tired this even with 0.10 but same result.

Comment: We are checking with Message Hub and BPM teams to see if they can offer advice.

Comment: Thanks Valerie. I have also opened this thread on developer works bluemix forum where i provided code snippets.      https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/291603/integrate-ibm-bpm-with-message-hub.html

Comment: Where is your BPM server running?

Comment: It runs my my local windows mc. BPM 8.5.6